# Flash Audio Player with Playlist Support?

Tags: flash, wordpress, mp3, playlist

So I am working on a wordpress theme where the admin can post mp3 files which in turn would show up on the front page as a list in a flash audio player. I already created the admin backend using custom post type but now I can't find a flash player that supports playlists to choose a song from. My client is not very choosy about the looks but it should look similar to this:
[image: flash audio player with playlist]

Is there any flash audio player that I can use for the purpose? I would rather not depend on XML based playlists. Commercial solutions are welcome as well.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is not flash, but perhaps jPlayer is a nice solution for you. It is build for audio, but it also supports video and playlists.

http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-02-video/

It is all html5. Which we love. Forever..

Comment: That's pretty nice. And definitely, we love HTML5. :-) But unfortunately, my client needs a flash solution.

Comment: http://www.podsnack.com/mp3-player-examples/players-with-playlists - 
http://www.flabell.com/flash/Flash-Mp3-Player-29 - 
http://webplayer.yahoo.com/ - 
http://www.flashmp3player.org/ - 
http://www.alsacreations.fr/dewplayer-en - 
http://www.premiumbeat.com/flash_music_players - 
http://www.strangecube.com/audioplay/ -  

You should meet Google, one of my very best friends ;)